# Access prototypal $scope functions in controller's constructor function

Tags: angularjs

Most of the angular new "styles" guide to replace anonymous controller functions with named constructor functions as this is the right angular way (pattern), even though the early documentation is not conforming.

E.g:

```
var testCtrl = function(){
    this.prop = 'Prop';
    ....
}

angular.module('app').controller('test', testCtrl);
```

I could understand the concept for the sake of debug-ability and memory savings.

My question:

If before you could listen to an event by subscribing with the `$scope.$on()` method:

```
angular.module( 'app' ).controller( 'test', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.$on('event', function (event, params) {
        ...
    });
}]);
```

how can you do it in a constructor function?

And there is a catch! Injecting the $scope in the constructor function and subscribing the event on the $scope will not execute the callback in the constructor function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, none of your examples have a named constructor function, they are just a different style to register a controller.

You could use a named contructor function for the sake of debug-ability in both styles, like this:

```
function testCtrl() {
  this.prop = 'Prop';
  ....
}

angular.module('app').controller('test', testCtrl);
```

Or this:

```
angular.module( 'app' ).controller( 'test', [ '$scope', function testCtrl( $scope ) {
  $scope.$on('event', function (event, params) {
    ...
  });
}]);
```

To subscribe events in the first style, you could do it like this:

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
  this.prop = 'Prop';

  $scope.$on('event', function (event, params) {
    ...
  });
}

angular.module('app').controller('test', ['$scope', testCtrl]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your last piece of code (the one that interests me) the callback function from the event listener is not executed in the same scope. If you log "this" in the callback it will be undefined, and the $scope does not have the `prop`.

Comment: You might be confused between JavaScript's Scope and AngularJS' scope, they are different things.

Comment: I am talking about the javascript scope. I found out that using a constructor function, with `controllerAs` (ui.router), the will be an instance of the controller in the angular scope. So I can access the `props` there.